# Perform operation on elements of numpy array using indexes list

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy array and two python lists of indexes with positions to increase arrays elements by one. Do numpy has some methods to vectorize this operation without use of `for` loops?

My current slow implementation:

```
a = np.zeros([4,5])
xs = [1,1,1,3]
ys = [2,2,3,0]

for x,y in zip(xs,ys): # how to do it in numpy way (efficiently)?
    a[x,y] += 1

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: As you treat some indices different than others, this won't be the result of one vectorized operation. You increment one index twice, the others only once.

Comment: @SpghttCd Exactly, I want to perform this operation as many times as much occurences are present in index list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.add.at` will do just that, just pass both indexes as a single 2D array/list:

```
a = np.zeros([4,5])
xs = [1, 1, 1, 3]
ys = [2, 2, 3, 0]

np.add.at(a, [xs, ys], 1) # in-place
print(a)

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = np.zeros([4,5])
>>> xs = [1, 1, 1, 3]
>>> ys = [2, 2, 3, 0]
>>> a[[xs,ys]] += 1
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```